# Run macro on cell click with variable target row

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to get an automatic transmission of a variable row as soon as the cell of column H of that row is selected. So if the user klicks H5, I would want the entire row 5 being copied to my worksheet "Rechnung" in I17.

This poor piece of code doesn't do the trick, because the range of the copied row isn't defined properly:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
  If Target.Column = Range("H1").Column Then
    Range(Target.Row).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Rechnung").Range("I17")
  End If
End Sub
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks and all the best,
Thomas

Comment: You can't copy an *entire* row and paste it in column 17. It won't fit. My guess is something like `Intersect(Target.EntireRow, Me.UsedRange).Copy Destination...`.

Comment: XY problem? http://xyproblem.info/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't copy an entire row and paste it into column 17... it won't fit.

Try using the `Intersect`ion of `Target.EntireRow` and the worksheet's `UsedRange`.

You can also use `Intersect` to check if `Target` includes a cell in column H:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
  If Intersect(Target, Me.Range("H:H")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
  If Intersect(Target, Me.UsedRange) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

  Intersect(Target.EntireRow, Me.UsedRange).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Rechnung").Range("I17")
End Sub
```